# Get only new entities from dataservice to client (feed?)

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I've just getted started with WCF Data Services, so I appologize if I do not make sense.

I'm creating an online event logger/viewer. To do this I have created an ado.net entity data model and a wcf data service. This works fine, and I'm able to add Events to my service.

I'm now working on creating a windows client to browse the events and I was wondering if there is any approach to updating the client with new events on a regular basis. As there will be a large amount of events it seems ineffective to download all the events for each and every refresh.

To provide more information, I can mention the following:
1. A custom TraceListener class in **software A** posts events to the data service.
2. Since wcf data services can act as a data source, I elected to go for this approach instead of a regular web service.
3. I'm currently creating the client in WPF.

I'm looking forward to any answers to this question.

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

WCF Data Services exposes your data using the OData protocol. This means that your client can easily query your data service using LINQ.

Per request that the client sends to the server, keep a timestamp. Next request, ask only for those events that occurred after the timestamp, using a LINQ query on your service reference-generated proxy.

```
var newEvents = myServiceRef.Events.Where(x => x.Timestamp >= lastTimestamp);
```

See also http://www.odata.org/ for more on the OData protocol, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622463.aspx for more on using LINQ to access WCF Data Services.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Do I manually add the new events to a separate collection in the client or is there some way to add the new query to the original one?